# How to name to semantic different elements with same styling in BEM?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

I have two elements in a block which are semantically different but should look the same, except little differences. How to name them in BEM?

1. same class for both with modifiers for each?
   (difficult because they are very different semantically)
2. different classes and assign them the same style? (lead to two or more places where the element is styled)
3. different classes and use CSS-Postprocessors to mixin the styles? (seems like the best option, in fact the naming problem is beeing tranfered to the name of the mixin)

What is best practise in BEM for this situation? Are there any recommendations?

Cheers, Jan

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a standard for this situation, but to minimize the edits needed in case one property changes and to mantain consistency, in plain CSS, I think the best practice could be this:

```
.elem1,.elem2{
  common-property:common-value;
  common-property:common-value;
}
.elem1{
  peculiarity:style;
}
.elem2{
  peculiarity:style;
}
```

If you like to keep multple CSSs or to divide your CSS following a semantic and/or page-section logic, I'd suggest to keep the common styles in a "general" CSS (section) and add the peculiarities in the respective CSSs/sections.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question and it is something I've been struggling a lot too!

Here's how I would do it in your case. Let's sum-up the two most important facts:

1. Components are **very different semantically**
2. They **should look almost the same**

Without knowing more context about the styles, it will be hard to say which is the best approach. Let's split it to 2 main cases.

The key here is that **you must make a decision** in which case you are:

- **Case 1**: if they are planned to have similar styles, therefore if the styles to the one change, the styles to the other should follow the same change too;
- **Case 2**: if these two elements just happen to have similar styles.

So, based on my experience, here's the approach I would recommend to you:

- **Case 1**: Just use a common class for both elements and use a modifier(s) for each (or for one) of them. Try to abstract as generic as possible, because the elements are very different semantically.

  For example, if the color is the same - abstract it by defining a `brand-color` variable/class/mixin. If the size is the same, abstract it by defining `container-width`. If the margin is the same, abstract it by by defining global `margin`.

  You might consider abstracting **not just one, but a few similar properties in different micro-abstractions** (like the examples) and **compose the mix of classes for each of the two elements**.
- **Case 2**: Use different classes and assign them the same style.

  Might not be that bad and you might actually benefit from that. If you think about it, these two elements just happen to have similar styles - no need to update both of them in case of a single style change.

Of course in all cases, make sure you do the enough to extend the global theme-specific properties (like `brand-color` for example), that should be consistent across all elements.

I hope my input helps!